# 240*320 android device specific dim file

Tags: android

I have an application that works with many devices and I have define dimen files based on low, medium , high and xhigh resolutions

but there is only one device with 240*320 size every thing is very small with it , it supposed to read from low dimen but it show thing so so small, so what can I do to make this device work withour affecting other resolutions

Answer (score 0):

240x320 size screens are considered 'small' screens. You can put any resources specific to that size screen in the `-small` directories (i.e., `layout-small`).

Comment: I have put that data in values-small folder and I have another device 240*400 and it is working fine with the values but the 240*320 show things very small

Comment: can I make a new values folder with this name values-w240dp-h320dp

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail - the w---dp and h---dp folders only work with Android 3.2+ devices. If the devices you are targeting are using an older version of Android, then the `-small` designation is the only size qualifier available. As the only difference between a 240x320 and 240x400 screen is vertical height, I would suggest making your layout flexible enough to support both (i.e., expand vertically to fill the space available).